# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on closest_point_on_mesh call in Ubuntu

Tags: python, scripting, linux

I triangulate an object and then call `obj.closest_point_on_mesh call()`. The call doesn't finish and my blender crashes. This happens only in Ubuntu, I also tried my python script in windows and it worked.

When I do not modify (I skip triangulation) the object, the call works fine also in Ubuntu. Any ideas how to handle this problem? Should I do anything with the object after triangulation?

Many thanks

Comment: No matter what you've done, a python call shouldn't cause a segfault. Can you create a minimal blend-file and script that would allow others to test this? Have you tested this with the most recent Blender version? If yes and the error still occurs this should be reported on the official bug tracker.

Comment: A bug report can be filed here after you have created an account: https://developer.blender.org Then open up Blender and go to the tab *Help > Report Bug*, it will auto populate your system information. Try to give specific instruction on how to reproduce the crash and attach your .blend file.

Comment: it's 2.79, so the most recent, except 2.8, which should still be in testing phase. Ok I will do so, thanks

Comment: 2.8 is considered current at the moment since we're already at the stage of a release candidate. Won't hurt to report this for 2.79b though.